# ASP wizard browser back button

Tags: asp.net, ajax, wizard

I used asp wizard with updatepanel and google map (it works great).
Wizard has 3 steps - all work's great, but when i click browser back button steps changed and i lose all previous information. When i click wizard previouse button - i can see my information.

i try this:
http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/ajax/HandlingTheBackButtonFromServerCode.aspx
but ScriptManager1.IsInAsyncPostBack always is false, and a hasn't hisotry - second problem: i want to get all information in this step

Maybe some other solutions??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want to put a square peg in a round hole.

If you want to navigate the wizard, use the wizard `previous`, `next` and `finish` buttons.

The browser `back` button is to move to another page, which is not a typical `ajax` application workflow and most definitely not the proper way to navigate a wizard control.

Comment: i used this 3 buttons, but my tipical user use back browser button instead of wizard previous button and therefore tries to find a solution